# Error: jQuery.imageMagnify is undefined Source File

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam getting a js error as " Error: jQuery.imageMagnify is undefined
Source File: file:///C:/Users/SS/Desktop/doing/jquery.magnifier.js
Line: 85"

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Posting your source code would help, especially the file that calls the libraries.  There really isn't anyone who can help when you just say "it's broken, help"